# Show that Hausdorff spaces are weak-Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> A topological space $X$ is weak Hausdorff if for any compact Hausdorff space $K$ and every continuous map $f:K \to X$, the image $f(K)$ is closed in $X$

I'm trying to show that Hausdorff spaces are indeed weak Hausdorff. I know that being Hausdorff can be characterized by: $X$ is Hausdorff if $\Delta X$ is closed in $X\times X$. These seems like it should be the approach to take but I can't see how to do it.

Maybe there is another characterization of weak-Hausdorff more suited to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the key ingredients:

1. The image of a compact space under a continuous function is compact.
2. A compact subspace of a Hausdorff space is closed.

These are very important exercises in point-set topology, and you should definitely make sure you can prove these statements yourself before you try learning about weak Hausdorff spaces. Assuming you know these two facts, the proof you're looking for is very simple:

Suppose $X$ is Hausdorff. Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $f : K \to X$ be a continuous map. Then $f(K)$ is compact, and since $X$ is Hausdorff we conclude that $f(K)$ is closed in $X$. $\square$